# A problem of decreasing iterative sequence infinitesimal order estimation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a strictly increasing function with

(1) $\forall b \ge 1$ we have  $f(\frac{1}{b})<\frac{1}{b+1}$.

(2) $\forall t > 1$ there exists $M\ge 1$ such that $b \ge M \implies f(\frac{1}{b})>\frac{1}{b+t}$.

We define a sequence $\{a_n\}$ by $$a_0 \in (0,1) \quad a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$$

Prove: $\lim_{n\to \infty} na_n=1$.

I can already give an upper bound of $a_n$ with $a_n<\frac{1}{n+1}$:

$$f(a_0)=a_1<\frac{1}{1/a_0+1}<\frac{1}{2}$$ which is implied by $a_0\in(0,1)$

Hence $$f(a_1)<f(\frac{1}{2})<\frac{1}{3}$$ By strict increase and induction we can get the upper bound.

But I failed to give a lower bound which is supposed to be implied by condition (2). I try to get the conclusion: for $k$ large enough there is $f(a_k)>\frac{a_k}{1+ta_k}$ for a fixed $t$, which may not work. I think a proper use of the condition "for arbitrary $t$" can give an answer. (Or the Stolz lemma?)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why is $f(1/2) < 1/3$?  EG Note that condition 1 is "there exists $b$", which could be (say) $b = 100$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ohhhh sorry that is an editing error... I have corrected it. The right version is $\forall b \ge 1.